# DllImport StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, dllimport, stack-overflow

I'm trying to use C++ DLL(borland c builder) from c#. Function writeParameter works fine, it writes correct data to a file, but then i have an exception "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll"

C++ code:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fwdreason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
  return 1;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma pack (push,1)
typedef struct     
{
     int     a;
}ABC;
#pragma pack (pop)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl writeParameter(ABC *abc)
{
   ofstream outfile("result.txt");
   outfile<< "A="   <<endl;
   outfile << abc->a <<endl;
   outfile.close();
}
```

c#:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class ABC
{
    public int a;
}
[DllImport("D:\\monitorVC.dll", EntryPoint = "_writeParameter", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern void WriteParameter( 
            [In,MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
            ABC abc
            );

        private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                var abc = new ABC() {a = 123};
                WriteParameter(abc);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Read this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam_nathan/archive/2003/04/23/56635.aspx) about the very poorly chosen name for UnmanagedType.LPStruct and how it does not do what everybody thinks it does.  Fix your declaration like this:

```
[DllImport(...)]
public static extern void WriteParameter([In] ref ABC abc);
```

Comment: Oops, this assumed that ABC is declared like a struct.  If you keep it a class then just drop the *ref* keyword.

Comment: The same. Function works (i.e. gets correct structure and writes it to a file) but then i have an StackOverflowException

Comment: It doesn't make sense with the given code.  But do use the debugger, Debug + Windows + Registers.  Look at the value of ESP before and after the call.  Also enable unmanaged code debugging and set a breakpoint on the C code so you can step it.

Comment: before  ESP = 0012E2A4 after ESP = 0012E2A4

Comment: That's just fine.  Something else is causing SO, not this function.  Look for an event handler that does something with side-effects that get the handler called again.

Comment: I have an empty wpf project: 1st window w/ button. Button shows second window. It works fine. But when i added DllImport it causes StackOverflowException in the line "Window2 win = new Window2();"

Comment: `code`private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
   var abc = new ABC() { a = 123 };
   ReadParametr(ref abc);
   Window2 win = new Window2();//throws StackOverflowException
   win.ShowDialog();
  }`code`

Comment: I've complied c++ DLL on BCB XE instead of BCB 6. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

class != struct in C#.

Also, the packing of your structure is not the same between the C# version and the C++ version.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's been a while since this question was posted but I had the same experience trying to load to a VS2010 C# project, a .dll built with CodeGear C++ Builder 2007.

The work-around was to remove all TForms from my .dll. It seemed to me that the exported symbols from these forms (which by the way I could not remove) where "leading" the loader to a stack overflow.

Regards.